# Create for loop through every cell in Column B,ifcell content is equal in Column C, change string's font color and make it bold

Tags: string, vba, fonts, colors

I have a list of idioms that I need to format to match a word in the cell to the left. An example is: If the word "Ant" is in B1, then C1 (which contains "The Ant is walking on the ground" should have only the word "Ant" formatted.

As can be seen, a for loop should run in each cell in Column C, and if the cell contains the string in Column B, it should be red and bold. This should only apply for that specific row, i.e. C1 only adheres to the content of B1, C2 to B2, etc.

At this moment I have tried a previous example VBA:

```
Sub test4String2color()
Dim strTest As String
Dim strLen As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
strTest = Worksheets("Makrogids").Cells(i, "B").Value


 strLen = Len(strTest)
For Each cell In Range(i, 3)
 If InStr(cell, strTest) > 0 Then
  cell.Characters(InStr(cell, strTest), strLen).Font.Color = vbRed
  cell.Characters(InStr(cell, strTest), strLen).Font.Bold = True
 End If
Next i
Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I get an error, and I cannot apply the code for each cell independently.

Any help?

Comment: What and where, plz always detail your errors, it is far more easier to help you fix it when we know where is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You crossed your loops, so it won't work like this!

Try this :

```
Sub test4String2color()

Dim strTest As String, _
    strLen As Integer, _
    i As Integer, _
    rCell As Range, _
    Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Makrogids")

For i = 1 To Ws.Range("C" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    strTest = Ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
    strLen = Len(strTest)
    If InStr(Ws.Cells(i, "C"), strTest) > 0 Then
        Ws.Cells(i, "C").Characters(InStr(Ws.Cells(i, "C"), strTest), strLen).Font.Color = vbRed
        Ws.Cells(i, "C").Characters(InStr(Ws.Cells(i, "C"), strTest), strLen).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next i

Set Ws = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Or this with the `For Each` loop :

```
Sub test4String2color()

Dim strTest As String, _
    strLen As Integer, _
    i As Integer, _
    rCell As Range, _
    Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Makrogids")

For Each rCell In Ws.Range(Ws.Range("C1"), Ws.Range("C" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    strTest = rCell.Value
    strLen = Len(strTest)
    If InStr(rCell, strTest) > 0 Then
        rCell.Characters(InStr(rCell.Value, strTest), strLen).Font.Color = vbRed
        rCell.Characters(InStr(rCell.Value, strTest), strLen).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next i

Set Ws = Nothing

End Sub
```